# login to my vnc session locally, from ubuntu login screen

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, vncserver

I setup a VNC server that I can successuly remotely connect to on my office ubunutu PC.

However, I can't access that desktop from the ubuntu login screen.

Is there any way I can login into my VNC session when locally accessing the PC?

Comment: Your qustion might have been answered here already http://askubuntu.com/questions/35396/how-to-access-an-ubuntu-machine-via-vnc-from-the-login-screen

Comment: Thanks, surprisingly I couldn't find it when I googled it.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a bone of contention for me. Raspbian jessie can do it, but for some reason ubuntu can't unless you use x11vnc which has been orphaned (with known bugs) since 2011.